# How to get elements of a vector of strings without the symbol [ ]

Tags: r, string, vector

How to get elements of a vector of strings without the symbol [1]?

```
v <- c("a","b","c")
for (i in seq_along(v)) {
  print(v[i])
}
```

Instead of getting "a", "b", "c" I obtained:

```
[1] "a"
[1] "b"
[1] "c"
```

But when I use `as.symbol`

```
for (i in seq_along(v)) {
  print(as.symbol(v[i]))
}
```

I obtain:

```
a
b
c
```

without any [ ]

Comment: Use `cat` instead of `print`

Comment: Or `writeLines`

Comment: Are you aware that R does not have scalars? Elements of a vector are length-one vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` is a function with a misleading name. A more accurate name would be `show_value_in_interactive_console` (but that’s a handful). Its purpose is really only for displaying values in the interactive R console. It is *not* suitable for other use.

When you actually want to display values to a user, or save them to a file, you do *not* want to use `print`. Instead, you want to use

- For displaying values to a user: `message` or `warning` (or `stop`)
- For persisting the text representation of values to a file or otherwise exposing them to the system: `writeLines`, `cat`

All of the above are usually used in combination with `format`, `sprintf`, `as.character` and `toString`, which perform the actual conversion of the value to text.

Oh, and `as.symbol` is completely unrelated to the above and shouldn’t be used here. It happens to work for your purpose purely by accident.

Comment: Not that I knew before the mere existence of `cat` and that it is preferable to use it to expose values to the system instead of `print`, but I only used `print` in my question to make it simpler. In fact, what I really wanted was to use `v[i]` and `as.symbol(v[i])` as args of a function. I was having difficulties and I thought erroneously that the reason was the `[ ]`. It wasn't and the function worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can print using `as.symbol` and if you need the index of the symbol just print `i` before

```
    for (i in seq_along(v)) {
      print(i)
      print(as.symbol(v[i]))
}
```

output will look like

```
0
a
1
b
2
c
```

Comment: `print` is the wrong way to do this 99% of the time.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I personally use "cat"  but I used print cause he was using it, so that it would be easyer to him to understand